# How to open and read files in a Windows Universal App using fopen

Tags: c++, fopen, c++-cx, win-universal-app

I'm writing a windows app (non-xaml) in c++ and trying to read files in my project directory using:

```
FILE* mFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
```

and I also tried:

```
errno_t err = fopen_s(&mFile, filename, "rb");
```

In this case, the errno is 2 and in both cases mFile is null afterwards.

I'm having trouble finding c++ code that explains how to simply open and read files. 
The filename is such: "./aDirectory/anotherDirectory/thefile"

My solution directory looks like with a lot of things omitted:

- AppName.Shared
- AppName.Windows 

  aDirectory

    anotherDirectory

      thefile
- AppName.WindowsPhone

I've seen something called a FilePicker in the API but it looks a little excessive and has more to do with UI than I need.

What is the appropriate way to include files into my project and then load them in Windows Runtime?

Comment: 2 means path not found. Check where your program thinks the working directory is with [GetCurrentDirectory ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx].

Comment: @user4581301 That link does not work, and according to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx , windows store apps cannot use GetCurrentDirectory

Comment: Gooned the link with a ] instead of a ). Sorry about that. Point is moot. Can you write a file to see where it winds up?

Comment: @user4581301 Unfortunately I cannot get writing to a file to work either. No luck

Comment: Is the Application data locations section on this page of any use? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Comment: @user4581301 I found the fix. It is in my edit.

Comment: So, Am I the only one thinking about that this is a C code? why not use the standard std::ifstream?

Comment: @DavidHaim Well I have a large codebase that I am trying to tweak and it is using fopen in many places. It was a lot easier to keep it using C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix. It turns out that my "directories" in my project structure were not actual directories, and that in Visual Studio they are "filters." So if I made the path "thefile" instead of ""./aDirectory/anotherDirectory/thefile," fopen would work.